# How do I check who shared my files in Google drive which I shared?

Tags: google-drive

**How do I check who shared my files in Google drive which I shared?**

Is it possible to see who shared my file from the link I've shared?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Drive allows you to do it out of the box, but am open to correction.

It's a bit of a hack, but [Google URL shortener](https://goo.gl/) or similar might do what you need as a workaround. Instead of sharing the link generated from Drive, you manually enter that into the URL shortener and share the link it outputs.